OAuth2 connection inconsistency using JSforce
My Nodejs app has the option for users to sign-in using their devOrg. And my app is establishing an OAuth2 connection using authorization code grant. The whole sign in works perfectly fine. After the sign in the user is successfully redirected back to the app.
But while testing using my personal devOrgs, I'm encountering an issue. Initially when I'm making these tooling api callouts below (getting logs of anonymous apex) they don't work. They return null even tho the user is successfully signed in and execute apex call works fine
This works:
sfConnection.tooling.executeAnonymous(userCode);

these calls don't work:
    const apexLog   = await sfConnection.tooling.query(`SELECT Id, Status, StartTime, LogUser.Name, Operation FROM ApexLog ORDER BY StartTime DESC LIMIT 1`);
    const apexLogId = apexLog.records[0].Id; // undefined
    const debugLogs = await sfConnection.requestGet(`${instanceUrl}/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ApexLog/${apexLogId}/Body`);

But I find that above code starts working immediately after I sign in to the said devOrg outside the nodejs app. I believe this is perhaps I'm authorising the org using a password?
These are scopes I've set in my Connected app

 const authURL = await oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({
        scope : 'api full web refresh_token',
        prompt: 'login',
    });

I can't seem to understand what the issue is. Is this something related to the authentication context or permissions associated with the OAuth2 session established by my application? Any pointers are appreciated.
